# Insert missing events into an ordered sequence of event records in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

I am experiencing a "data fix" problem in Postgres: 
Imagine there is a user-event table, with timestamp, event name, and userID. The question is: how can I put/fix specific event back to the table and update it with user-define-conditions?

Here is the example:

`original table
timestamp     event   userID 
2017-01-01   A          01
2017-01-02   C          01
2017-01-03   D          01`

how can I insert a new row to this table with specific conditions,

the condition is 

`if a user has the events A -> C -> D  (time ordering ),
then we should fix that with A -> B -> C -> D  (time ordering )
(put event B back)`

`modified table :
timestamp event userID 
2017-01-01 A      01 
2017-01-02 B      01
2017-01-02 C      01
2017-01-03 D      01`

Have tried some approaches via python / PL/pgSQL, but still, have no idea

---

Notice: there may be multiple userID in the table, so the general case may be :

`original table
timestamp     event   userID 
2017-01-01   A          01
2017-01-02   C          01
2017-01-03   D          01
2017-01-01   A          02
2017-01-02   C          02
2017-01-03   D          02
2017-01-01   A          03
2017-01-02   C          03
2017-01-03   D          03`

`modified table
timestamp     event   userID 
2017-01-01   A          01
2017-01-02   B          01
2017-01-02   C          01
2017-01-03   D          01
2017-01-01   A          02
2017-01-02   B          02
2017-01-02   C          02
2017-01-03   D          02
2017-01-01   A          03
2017-01-02   B          03
2017-01-02   C          03
2017-01-03   D          03`

Comment: Hint:  `INSERT`.

Comment: Can you be more specific on these conditions?

Comment: From what you described so far, the answer is `INSERT INTO table VALUES ('2017-01-03', 'D', '01');` What in particular about that basic INSERT is different from what you want to do?

Comment: hi @GordonLinoff
should i do the for-loop- insert in Posgres?
thanks

Comment: hi @JimJones

the conditions is :

if a user has the events ```A -> C -> D ``` (time ordering ),
then we should fix that with ```A -> B -> C -> D ``` (time ordering )
(put event B back)

Comment: hi @VoteyDisciple
yes basically is ```INSERT INTO table VALUES ('2017-01-03', 'C', '01');```
, but how can i do that for all rows fit the conditions  in that table?

Comment: I suggest changing the title into something like: `Insert missing events  into an ordered sequence of event records`

Comment: hi @wildplasser
sure! thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LAG()` window function allows you to refer to the `previous` record in a given `window`. (The CTE is for readability, in practice, a subquery could *perform* better):

---

```
-- The data
CREATE TABLE abcd
        ( ztimestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , zevent   CHAR(1)
        , zuserID integer
        );

INSERT INTO abcd ( ztimestamp , zevent , zuserID ) VALUES
 ('2017-01-01', 'A', 1) ,('2017-01-02', 'C', 1) ,('2017-01-03', 'D', 1)
,('2017-01-01', 'A', 2) ,('2017-01-02', 'C', 2) ,('2017-01-03', 'D', 2)
,('2017-01-01', 'A', 3) ,('2017-01-02', 'C', 3) ,('2017-01-03', 'D', 3)
        ;

-- The INSERT-query:
WITH triple AS (
        SELECT zuserID, zevent
        , LAG(zevent,2) OVER www AS must_be_a
        , LAG(zevent,1) OVER www AS must_be_c
        , LAG(ztimestamp,1) OVER www AS c_timestamp
        , LAG(zevent,0) OVER www AS must_be_d
        FROM abcd
                WINDOW www AS (PARTITION BY zuserID ORDER BY ztimestamp)
        )
INSERT INTO abcd ( ztimestamp , zevent , zuserID )
SELECT t.c_timestamp, 'B', t.zuserID
FROM triple t
WHERE t.must_be_a = 'A'
AND t.must_be_c = 'C'
AND t.must_be_d = 'D'
        ;


SELECT zuserID, ztimestamp, zevent
FROM abcd
ORDER BY 1,2,3
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
INSERT 0 3
 zuserid |     ztimestamp      | zevent 
---------+---------------------+--------
       1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | A
       1 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | B
       1 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | C
       1 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00 | D
       2 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | A
       2 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | B
       2 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | C
       2 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00 | D
       3 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | A
       3 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | B
       3 | 2017-01-02 00:00:00 | C
       3 | 2017-01-03 00:00:00 | D
(12 rows)
```

---

For reference, below is how we used to do these kind of things *before* the introduction of `WINDOW` functions:

---

```
INSERT INTO abcd ( ztimestamp , zevent , zuserID )
SELECT c.ztimestamp, 'B' , c.zuserID
FROM abcd c
JOIN abcd a ON a.zuserID = c.zuserID
        AND a.ztimestamp < c.ztimestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT*FROM abcd x
                WHERE x.zuserID = a.zuserID
                AND x.ztimestamp > a.ztimestamp
                AND x.ztimestamp < c.ztimestamp
                )
JOIN abcd d ON d.zuserID = c.zuserID
        AND d.ztimestamp > c.ztimestamp
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT*FROM abcd x
                WHERE x.zuserID = d.zuserID
                AND x.ztimestamp > c.ztimestamp
                AND x.ztimestamp < d.ztimestamp
                )
WHERE c.zevent  = 'C'
        ;
```

Comment: hi @wildplasser
thanks for the idea, that query seems can work on the example case.
but what if there are 100 userID and 100 timestamp 
in that table ?  it's not easy to hardcode all need-to-insert data in sql

Comment: Nothing is hardcoded, except the ACD values. And the B value. (and the offsets.)

Comment: hi @wildplasser 
sorry it's my bad lol, there is no hardcode
Yes, the query works fine on my side 
i am trying to implement that to my dataset 
thanks !

Comment: hi @wildplasser
what if some events can exist multiple times?
i.e. ```A->B->B->D``` to ```A->B->B->C->D```  ?

Comment: Well, that is not in your original question, or in your sample data. But in that case: a record will **not** be inserted. In another case (also not in your example)  `A->C->D->A->C->D`, **two** `B` records would be inserted.

Comment: @ wildplasser 
yeah that's different from my original question, 
but that's the real case. maybe I should open up the other new question to consider the multiple cases?
i.e. 
```A->C->D``` or 
```A->C->C->D``` or 
```A->A->C->D``` or 
```A->C->D->D``` or 
``A->A->C->D->D``` or 
...

Answer (score 0):

This seems way too overly complex, and there are probably much more efficient ways to do it, but:

```
insert into aa
select '2017-01-02', 'B', a1.userID
from aa a1, aa a2, aa a3
where a1.userID = a2.userID
and a2.userID = a3.userID
and a1.event = 'A'
and a2.event = 'C'
and a3.event = 'D'
and a1.userID in (select userID
                  from aa
                  group by userID
                  having count(distinct event) = 3);
```

Comment: You need to check the *order* of the events, too. And: there should not be additional events between A->C and C->D

Comment: hi @Abdul Ahad 
thanks for the idea, but what if the timestamp and userid 
are not unchange in the table ?

is there a flexible way?
thanks

Comment: @J.Liu what do you want the timestamp to be?

Comment: @wildplasser additional events are handled by the group by, the order can be added with a1.timestamp < a2.timestamp and a2.timestamp < a3.timestamp

Comment: hi @AbdulAhad 
the timestamp can let me calculate how long the event period is
i.e. time period between event A, B... and so on

Comment: @J.Liu well, you can select whatever you want the value to be.  a2.timestamp for example instead of the hardcoded value '2017-01-02'